# What is the file path to access a shared LAN samba server from android?

Tags: android, python, samba

I am using an Android tablet running python to access a shared file running off samba in ubuntu from a NUC. I have no problem connecting to this file from my computer in windows using "\\192.168.1.55\mhs" but this does not work for Android.

I have already made use of the "X-plorer" app from the play store, which is a 3rd party file manager. This app can access the shared file just fine, but that does not give me access to a python file path.

Comment: There is nothing in Android for accessing Windows network shares.

Comment: The shared folder is running off of samba in ubuntu (Linux), not windows. I said the file was accessible through windows, wondering how to access from android.

Comment: "The shared folder is running off of samba in ubuntu (Linux), not windows" -- that does not really change the issue. There is nothing in Android for accessing SMB/CIFS network shares, whether they are served from Windows, Ubuntu, or anything else.

Comment: I am able to access the shared folder from android using a 3rd party file manager that can access the shared folder's ip. Is there any way to route through this app to allow access?

Comment: You would have to ask the authors of that app. That app is probably using a SMB/CIFS library like jCIFS to access the SMB/CIFS share. Perhaps there is an equivalent Python library that you could use.

Comment: would a library like pysmb be viable in this case?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know enough Python to answer that question.